# How are fission products formed?

Tags: nuclear-chemistry

I know this question may seem a bit simple, but I would like to know about how fission products of an element are formed. There seems to be no way for krypton-92 and barium-141, the immediate fission products of U235, to decay into a fission product like caesium-137 or technetium-99. Instead, I found they quickly decay to the stable nuclides zirconium-91, zirconium-92, and praseodymium-141, and the intermediate radioactive nuclides all have half-lives of within a few months.

So, my question is, how are these other fission products formed?

Comment: @Poutnik Then how are they formed?

Comment: @Poutnik But the fission of uranium-235 seems to only produce krypton-92 and barium-141.

Comment: It is false premise I have tried to negate since the beginning. See also [Fission product yield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission_product_yield)

Comment: Comments moved to the answer.

Comment: i wonder why the popular texts as well as a lot of textbooks are concentrated exactly on the Ba / Kr example

Comment: @fraxinus Yes, that was why I had a misconception about nuclear fission.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are *many* immediate primary fission products, with 2 probability peaks near 2/5 and 3/5 of original uranium-235 nucleon number. By other words, there are multiple ways how the nucleus can be broken, some more probable than others.

> But the fission of uranium-235 seems to only produce krypton-92 and barium-141.

This is false premise. These are just the products of a single fission mode from many. In a classical analogy, there is multiple ways how to break a stone.

See also [Nuclear fission products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_fission_product) and [Fission product yield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fission_product_yield)